# OpenCV Android implementing ORB in AndroidStudio

Tags: opencv, orb, android

Where can I find a demo/tutorial of using ORB with OpenCV in AndroidStudio. I searched the web any way I could but I did not find anything that would help me.

I want to write an Android app that will detect multiple flat objects in a live video stream from the camera, and Log their appearance in a logfile.

After researching a little on the web I believe the best approach would be using SURF or ORB. However, SURF I believe it's now unavailable since it was aquired by quallcom, it is also not opensource nor free, my best bet would be with ORB but I cannot find any tutorial on how to implement this for Android

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: any progress on this - are the OpenCV samples understandable?

Answer (score 0):

General information about how to start with Android+OpenCV can be found **[here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html)**. Unfortunately it is a little bit outdated since it does not use the new AndroidStudio. But the steps are similar.

If you have done this, start using 1) feature detection 2) feature description and then 3) Use a homography to detect your flat object.
This is explained **[here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography)**, unfortunately only in C++. But the java code is nearly identical - your code completion will help you with that.

Comment: Unfortunatelly the second link does not work... and that one seems pretty important. Please update it